# HDR to SD using CUDA

Tags: hdr

This is a pretty well known process for HDR to SD. Is there a way to use this or similar with CUDA/NVEnc?

ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,
zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,
format=yuv420p -c:v libx265 -crf 18 -preset slower output.mkv